# Puzzling behavior from Java.Random.nextInt()

Tags: java

I'm implementing a SkipList.  At one point in the algorithm, we are to toss a coin, and do something over and over as long as it keeps coming up heads, and stop as soon as we see tails.  I was letting odd numbers represent "heads" by using:

```
while (R.nextInt() % 2 == 1)
```

But this yielded a heads only about 25% of the time (out of 50,000-ish calls).  Changing it to

```
while (R.nextBoolean())
```

produces heads half of the time, as expected.  R is instantiated as a Random, seeded with System.currentTimeMillis().  It appears that the bit stream generated by Random is not so uniformly distributed after all.  Has anyone else seen such behavior?

I also tried it with:

```
while (Math.random() >= 0.5)
```

and got the 50/50 (give-or-take) behavior I was expecting.

It also seems to work just fine with:

```
while (R.nextInt(2) == 1)
```

It just doesn't seem to generate 32-bit integers with the LSB 0 anywhere NEAR half of the time.  Seems that, at the bit level, we should be able to expect randomness, too.  Maybe it's the linear congruence they're using; maybe I'm missing something, but this seems to be a problem.  I realize there are "better" PRNGs available, and I already have a couple of perfectly viable work-arounds; I just wanted to report what I observed.

Answer (score 6):

> nextInt()
>   Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number generator's sequence.

Integer types are signed in Java, and possible results of doing modulo `2` operation are: `-1` (negative odd), `0` (even), `1` (positive odd).

`nextInt() % 2` would be equal to `1` only for positive odd integers, that's why you get only 25%. You need a small change in the condition:

```
 while (R.nextInt() % 2 != 0)
```

Comment: Interesting -- I thought the % always produced something between 0 and (modulus - 1) (i.e., anything mod 5 must be 0 - 4, inclusive).  I did try using 
`while ((R.nextInt() & 1) == 1)`
and that seemed to work as expected, too.

Comment: @user8887287 If you want that, use Math.floorMod instead.

Answer (score 2):

In Java `(n*2+1) % 2` is -1 if `n` is negative. (This is quite annoying as it doesn't make much mathematical sense but it is what it is. It is however consistent with how the `/` operator works, so `(a/b)*b+(a%b)=a` for all `a` and `b`, unless integer overflow happens.)

Since `Random.nextInt()` returns a signed random number, the modulo will be 0 50% of the time, -1 25% of the time and 1 25% of the time.

Of course you can switch to `r.nextInt() % 2 != 0` or `r.nextInt() == 0` but the most readable solution is indeed just using  `r.nextBoolean()`.